# How to use variable in xpath in R?

Tags: r

when i parse  a web file, it works fine ,

```
tdata=xpathApply(data,"//table[@id='PL']")
```

i want to use variable in xpathApply,

```
x="PL"
tdata=xpathApply(data,"//table[@id=x]")
```

it can not work,how to write the xpath expression in xpathApply with variable?

think for Dason's suggestion,

```
x="PL"
y=paste0("//table[@id='",x,"']")
tdata=xpathApply(data,y)
```

it is ok,but i feel it is ugly,how can i write it more beautiful?

Comment: Read `?paste` or `?paste0` or `?sprintf`

Comment: You could make your question "more beautiful" by paying greater attention to capitalization, spelling, and grammar.

Comment: @Dason, can you please post your comment as an answer so Dada Lili can accept it as solved?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Looks like there are good enough answers now.  I was just tired and didn't feel like writing up an answer.  Although to be honest of this is a duplicate (or at least close enough to a duplicate) or something I would surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dason's suggestion of using `paste` or one alike is most likely the only way to go. If you find it ugly, you can sweep it under the rug by creating your own function:

```
my.xpathApply <- function(data, x) xpathApply(data, paste0("//table[@id='",x,"']"))
tdata <- my.xpathApply(data, "PL")
```

After all, you must use a lot of package functions that use `paste` somewhere, so you should be ok with having one of your own :-)

Answer (score 3):

The gsubfn package can do string interpolation somewhat along the lines of Perl if we preface the function whose arguments are to contain substitutions with `fn$`.  Here `$x` means substitute in the value of `x` .  See ?fn and the [gsubfn home page](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com).

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- "PL"
tdata <- fn$xpathApply(data, "//table[@id='$x']")
```

Comment: Is `x` a "reserved" name? I'm asking because `x <- 1; fn$print('$x')` returns `"NA"` (though no warning) while it works as expected i.e., returns `"1"` if I name the variable something else. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: `x <- 1; fn$print("$x")` works for me.  Are you using an old version of gsubfn?  The latest version is 0.6.4.